# How do I parse the results from a JSON output into a data frame?

Tags: json, r, dataframe

In trying to analyze tweets from a hashtag, I am able to obtain 100 results at a time via this call.

```
curl -i "http://otter.topsy.com/search.json?q=esa2012&window=a&perpage=100&offset=0" >> esa2012_0.json
```

resulting in a file like [this](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2223411/esa2012_0.json) (JSON file in link).

How do I read this into `R` and convert it to a `data.frame`?

Thus far I am able to skip the first several (non-JSON) lines like so:

```
library(XML)
library(RJSONIO)
file0 <- scan(file = "~/Desktop/data/esa2012_0.json", skip = 18, what= "raw")
```

but the resulting read becomes difficult to coerce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fromJSON(file0)` should do it.

I typically run it with `,simplify=FALSE` and construct the data.frame myself rather than trying to have it simplify for me.

Note you don't need the command line call to `curl` if you use the RCurl library:

```
library(RJSONIO)
library(RCurl)
j <- getURL("http://blah?mine=yours")
fromJSON(j)
```

Comment: You're kind-of right for `RCurl`, and I'd also rather use that one than system call, but sometimes passing simple `intern = TRUE` in `system` will do the trick...

Comment: That worked, the data was embedded in list item 2 and the 7th list. I just had to pull those out. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @Maiasaura Sure.  I just happened to have the code up in another window anyhow. :-)